# How to make a for loop read files using a specific pattern

Tags: python, operating-system

I extracted a lot of images from a video and now I have folder that has the following names:

1. frame1.jpg
2. frame2.jpg
3. ....
4. frame10.jpg
5. frame11.jpg
6. frame12.jpg
7. ....
8. frame101.jpg
9. frame102.jpg
10. ....

I used this code to try and transform each image:

```
 `for files in os.listdir("./images1"):
          do something to tranform`
```

I printed the file names and they were not coming out in order. They were coming out like this `1,10,100,1000,1000` then `11,12,13,14`. I would like an output of,`1,2,3,4,5...` since it's a video and chronological order is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
my_list = ["frame1.jpg", "frame10.jpg", "frame101.jpg", "frame102.jpg", "frame11.jpg", "frame12.jpg", "frame2.jpg"]
my_list.sort(key=lambda name: int(name[5:-4]))
print(my_list)
```

Explanation:

```
key=lambda name: int(name[5:-4])
```

is the the function that is used to sort, it extracts the part of the name string that correspond to the number of your frame and converts it to `int`.

Now you just need to plug in `my_list = os.listdir("./images1")`, sort it, and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path exactly then you can also try this:

```
folder_path = "<insert folder location>" 

for i in range(1, no_of_frames):
     file_name = f"{folder_path}/frame{i}.jpg"
     do what you want here
```